# Gzip stops autocomplete in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete, gzip

I'm using codeigniter as framework for my project. I'm trying to gzip my files from config file which is

```
$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;
```

But when I keep following varaiable to TRUE, one of my form's textbox which consist autocomplete stops working.
Auto complete code is such

```
$(function() {
$( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: baseurl + "home/auto_search",
            data: { searchfor : $("#textbox").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
}); });
```

This returns output which I can see from firebug, but it does not popup results.
And I've to compress my output through this.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling exit() after echoing the json in the controller.